# No longer able to to Push to bitbucket using Xcode 10.1

Tags: xcode, git, authentication, bitbucket

I've been using the same git repository for over a year without issue.
However, this week, I am now receiving the following issue when attempting to push code to Bitbucket Cloud: "Authentication failed because the credentials were rejected."
I am using Https. I've tried SSH and it fails as well.
Also, it's important to note that I'm able to Push using Source Tree without issue.
I've searched extensively, and I haven't found any hits with the same situation. I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14. and  Xcode 10.1,
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
[image]